# publisher can only in While? no, maybe other reason

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After execute the following code, the subscriber CANNOT receive msg.
I start this publisher by :
**python demo_pub.py   or
rosrun demo demo_pub.py**.
And start the Subscriber in terminal by :
**rostopic echo /chatter**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# license removed for brevity
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker')
    hello_str = "hello world %s" % rospy.get_time()
    rospy.loginfo(hello_str)
    pub.publish(hello_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

When I show the rqt_graph, it shows that they have been get linked.

But when I add while loop like this, it works well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# license removed for brevity
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talker():
    pub = rospy.Publisher('chatter', String, queue_size=10)
    rospy.init_node('talker')
    rate = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        hello_str = "hello world %s" % rospy.get_time()
        rospy.loginfo(hello_str)
        pub.publish(hello_str)
        rate.sleep()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        talker()
    except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
        pass
```

Also, I need to restart the subscriber when I restart the demo_pub file. And how can I publish a message only once?

---

The code has nothing wrong.

I figure out the reason but cannot get the answer.

After I change the master_urI value within .bashrc to other IP address, and then run " roscore" in the terminal of device with that IP, then the strange problem reappeared again.

So, each time I change the master of roscore, I restart my ubuntu system will help.

I just run "source .bashrc", and restart the terminal before.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293771/publisher-can-only-in-while?-no,-maybe-other-reason./) by [suoxd123](https://answers.ros.org/users/35391/suoxd123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suoxd123](https://answers.ros.org/users/35391/suoxd123/) on 2018-06-11**:
Even if I add the following code after publish,the subscriber still cannot get msg.

```
rate = rospy.Rate(10)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
     rate.sleep()
```

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2018-06-11**:
It's look fine, can you add the code of your Subscriber ?

**Comment by [suoxd123](https://answers.ros.org/users/35391/suoxd123/) on 2018-06-11**:
Thanks, I just check it on terminal by

```
rostopic echo /chatter
```

**Comment by [suoxd123](https://answers.ros.org/users/35391/suoxd123/) on 2018-06-11**:
And  Even for the while code, when I restart the publish file , the Subscriber need to be restart for receiving msg.

**Comment by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) on 2018-06-11**:
Do you start the `rostopic echo /chatter` before or after the node ? I can't reprodruce any problem with your code

**Comment by [suoxd123](https://answers.ros.org/users/35391/suoxd123/) on 2018-06-11**:
Thanks, I have exec it on terminal before I run the  demo_pub.py.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The code has nothing wrong.

my master on raspberry and nodes on ubuntu system of PC.

Last night I recharge the raspberry's li battery and this morning the code works fine.

The problem cannot reappear again, I guess there is 2 possible reason.

1. Battery is under voltage, so it works well after recharged.
2. I restart the raspberry device and Ubuntu system, so
   the ros system is reset also.

After I change the master uri, the problem happened. And I restart my ubuntu system, the problem disappeared.

---

Originally posted by [suoxd123](https://answers.ros.org/users/35391/suoxd123/) with karma: 11 on 2018-06-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-11**:
Please don't use an *answer* to provide more information about your *question*. This isn't a forum. Please update your question with this information instead.

**Comment by [suoxd123](https://answers.ros.org/users/35391/suoxd123/) on 2018-06-11**:
ok, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think I got it :

There is 2 possible problem here :

1. You didn't close your subscriber : If you registered your subscriber (in your case : rosptopic echo /chatter) with a roscore, then you closed this roscore and open a new one, the subscriber will not receive any message from the new roscore.
   You can check it by :

- Open a roscore
- Send a message to /chatter
- Open your subscriber to /chatter
- Close your roscore
- Open your roscore again
- Send a message to /chatter, nothing will happen

2. Your publisher didn't have the time to send the message. Ros need some time to setup the publisher/Subscriber : https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/176 or https://answers.ros.org/question/11167/how-do-i-publish-exactly-one-message/

Try to properly restart your roscore and subscriber and then try to add a little wait after your rospy.Publisher() to see if this works now.

---

Originally posted by [lmathieu](https://answers.ros.org/users/30984/lmathieu/) with karma: 591 on 2018-06-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [suoxd123](https://answers.ros.org/users/35391/suoxd123/) on 2018-06-11**:
Thank you so much for the detail explainning.

1. I didnot close or restart roscore.
2. I add the loop sleep, but cannot
   work as well.